# How can I loop through a string that holds multiple errors?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to write a log for each error that gets stored into `validationErrors` variable. So for instance, depending on what I do the `validationErrors` may contain one or more error message. In this one scenario, if I do not select a checkbox nor enter a value in the textfield I would get back the following errors: Enter a phone number! and Select a checkbox.

So I was trying to loop through each log so I can have a separate log for each error message, but when I try I only get the first character. How can I achieve this?

```
.....

string validationErrors = string.Join(", ", ModelState.Values.Where(E => E.Errors.Count > 0)
                                         .SelectMany(E => E.Errors)
                                         .Select(E => E.ErrorMessage)
                                         .ToList());

                    foreach (var item in validationErrors)
                    {
                        _logger.LogError(item.ToString());
                    }
                

              //      _logger.LogError(validationErrors); this will only write one log for both errors

   throw new Exception(ValidationErrors);
```

You can see here the second log is separated by a comma.
[image]

Is this what you mean by looping over `ModelState.Values` to log each error before creating a single string?

```
                    foreach (var item in ModelState.Values)
                    {
                        _logger.LogError(item.Errors.Select(E => E.ErrorMessage));
                    }
```

Comment: Why not loop over `ModelState.Values` to log errors _before_ joining its results into a single string?

Comment: @SeanSkelly In my updated post, is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes to the `foreach` line; it's up to you how you want to implement the line(s) inside the loop.  Seems simpler this way.  (As an aside - note that joining strings with a comma delimiter when the strings themselves may contain commas might not be the best idea.  In this scenario, the `string.Split` answer may not give you the results you expect in all cases.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looping over a string itself treats the string as an `char[]` and you therefor iterate over each charachter individually.

To loop over a string that contains multiple values you need to split it into multiple strings first. You can use `string.Split` to do this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/parse-strings-using-split

```
foreach(var validationError in validationErrors.Split(','))
{
  // Do stuff.
}
```

In the use case you posted the values are merged first. That step could be skipped.

```
var validationErrors = ModelState.Values.Where(E => E.Errors.Count > 0)
  .SelectMany(E => E.Errors)
  .Select(E => E.ErrorMessage)
  .ToList();

foreach(var validationError in validationErrors)
{
  // Do stuff.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using this

```
public static string ValidateModelState(ModelStateDictionary modelState)
        {
        var errorMessage = "";

            if (!modelState.IsValid)
            {
                foreach (var item in modelState.Values)
                {
                    foreach (var modelError in item.Errors)
                    {
                        errorMessage += "\n" + "Error: " + modelError.ErrorMessage;
                    }
                }
            }
            return errorMessage;
        }
```

I use it this way

```
var errorMessage = ValidateModelState(ModelState);
if( !string.IsNullOrEmpty(errorMessage)) return BadRequest(errorMessage);

//or you can use it 

if( !string.IsNullOrEmpty(errorMessage)) _logger.LogError(errorMessage);
```

Comment: Thank you, so in my case, I would need to have `_logger.LogError(errorMessage)` after your `errorMessage` line correct?

Comment: I follow now! Thank you!! :)